# How can I bring a minimized modeless WinForm to its previously displayed position programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

To bring a modeless Windows Form to its previous position upon a click event, I am trying to use the code shown below, but its not working.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

```
public void SetFocus()
{
    this.Focus();
    this.BringToFront();
    if (this.WindowState==FormWindowState.Minimized)
        this.Select();
}
```

Comment: "its not working" is not very much to go on when trying to come up with a solution remotely. Can you describe *in what way* it is not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the form is minimized and you want to make it visible, you'll need to *restore* it. You do this by setting its [`WindowState` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate.aspx) to `FormWindowState.Normal`.

For example, change your code to this instead:

```
public void SetFocus()
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    this.Focus();
    this.BringToFront();
}
```