# Can not Focus() onto a Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, windows-8, focus

I tried:

```
Form myForm = new EULA();
myForm.Show();
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
myForm.BringToFront();
myForm.Activate();
myForm.Focus();
```

This code brings it to the front, but for some reason I still have to click on the Form for it to have focus, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Can you show how myForm is defined?

Comment: Why minimized?  Likely you're encountering the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849888/how-can-i-bring-a-minimized-modeless-winform-to-its-previously-displayed-positio

Comment: If you need your current form to wait on `myForm` then you could use `myForm.ShowDialog()`, which should bring the form to front and focus on it until it's closed.

Comment: Have you tried setting the focus to a control on the form?

Comment: @holtavolt It's minimizing itself, and making a new form, and focusing on it, not trying to focus itself. programmer93 That's what I had first, but I need the original form to run some code while the other one has focus, so I can't do that. ron I'll try that real quick

Comment: @rontornambe It didn't work, maybe I did it wrong? I did `myForm.Controls["richTextBox1"].Focus();`

Comment: For me it works as expected (code from question). Tried to launch it on different machine/user?

Comment: @erem I just tried it on my parents' account, and it didn't work there either

Comment: Oh, Windows 8, this can be the reason why it works here, on Win7 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi leaf68 just follow my codes. try to figure it out :)

Let say we have `MainForm` and `LoginForm`

In our project we have a `Static Class` we called `Program` -> *The main entry point for the application.* as default class to `run` our projects.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.Run(new LoginForm());

        if (LoginForm._loginSuccess)
        {
            var m = new MainForm();
            Application.Run(m);
        }
        else
            Application.Exit();
    }

    public static bool UserLogin() //Add some parameter
    {
        //You Logic here
        LoginForm._loginSuccess = true;
        return LoginForm._loginSuccess;
    }
}
```

then this is our `LoginForm` codes

```
   public partial class LoginForm : Form
    {
        public LoginForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static bool _loginSuccess { get; set; }
        public event EventHandler Login;

        private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Program.UserLogin())
            {
                Close();
                Dispose();

                if (Application.OpenForms.Count > 0)
                    if (Application.OpenForms["MainForm"].Name == "MainForm")
                    {
                        Application.OpenForms["MainForm"].WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                        Application.OpenForms["MainForm"].Enabled = true;
                    }
                if (Login != null)
                    Login(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
```

then assuming that we successfully `Login` To `MainForm` so this is our `MainForm` codes

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void logOutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Hide();
        Enabled = false;
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        var f = new LoginForm();
        f.Login += loginShow;
        f.Show();
        f.Activate();
    }

    private void loginShow(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Show();
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thank you, this is even better than what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

The form may be focused already, perhaps you want a control inside it (like a textbox or a combo) to be selected instead?

I'll use this code at the form's load method:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{ 
  controlName.Select();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a form not visible, so only the tray icon.

I just use:

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
this.Activate();
```

In the above order. Program comes to the front and is activated, meaning typing actually writes in the active field.

This works:

- when program appears automatically and
- when user selects tray menu item.

Comment: The form I'm trying to Focus on is a child of my main form, which I need to be minimized.

Comment: That's not possible.  If it is actually a child window (how did it get to be one?) then minimizing the parent is going make the child disappear as well.

Comment: I guess I said it wrong, by child I mean it is owned by my main form, because the form I'm trying to focus on is not minimized when my main form is.