# Form TextBox values to Form2 TextBox values

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Basically when a user enters data into a `textfield` on `Form2`, I want that data to be stored into a variable then when users selects the button enter, `Form2` will hide and `Form1` will appear. I then want `Form1` to display the data entered in the `textfield` from `Form2` in a new `textfield`.

This is my attempt, but it doesn't work

On Form 2...

```
public string Player1 {get; set;}

private void pvpPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Player1 = txtPlayer1.Text;
        Form1 op = new Form1();
        op.Show();
        this.Hide();

    }
```

Then on Form1 to call this I put...

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
txtTest.Text = f.Player1;
```

But it doesn't work. Hopefully someone knows the answer.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061746/can-not-focus-onto-a-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer the using of a simple Callback function like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public String SomeProperty { get; set; }

    private void OpenFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var secondForm = new Form2()
        {
            GetSomeProperty = () => { return SomeProperty ;};
        };
        this.Hide(); //The best way to hide!
        secondForm.Show();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SomeProperty = "HELLO WORLD";
    }
}



public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Func<string> GetSomeProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(GetSomeProperty.Invoke());
    }
}
```

Everytime you call `GetSomeProperty.Invoke();` the Func will call the get accessor and return it from the first Form

Comment: OK I'll have a go at this now =)

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any troubles ;-)

Comment: again, this will display the value to `Form1` but the `Form2` will not hide :)

Comment: Wow, I'm such a newbie lol... I tried this code, but it doesn't even do anything? :/

Comment: @spajce Do you really try to hide it or just minimize it?@GlenHunter thats very vague, please describe the problem

Comment: Sorry I was really tired last night, ok I entered the code you provided me and it doesn't do anything. Is your code that you provided supposed to display a message box? How do I tell this function to get the input from my textPlayer1.Text in form2 and then place it into my form 1 after it's opened, into the text field textTest.Text? Hope that makes sense

Comment: No problem. No you can use it to do anything, for example you can get the Property and set it into another like this: `var buff = GetSomeProperty.Invoke()`. Are you sure that you realy wrode `var secondForm = new Form2()
        {
            GetSomeProperty = () => { return SomeProperty ;};
        };
`? rename `SomeProperty` with that variable or Property in your first Form and this variable or Property will retrun if you call `GetSomeProperty.Invoke()` anyhow.
Please post your code with a Delegate that will be the best.

Comment: Hey finally, I did it, I think I got mixed up because the code you provide assumes that the user starts on Form1, however... in my application it's the other way round, form2 loads up then user navigates to form1, but I've done it now! Thanks! Do you know where I can find an explanation of the code you provided? Like a break down. 

Thanks for your help ^.^

Comment: Feel free to ask ;-). Yes there are many questions about that and i'm writing on a Q/A for that, i will post the link as soon as it is finished

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455889/communication-between-winforms/14455891#14455891

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is **overload** the `Form1` constructor.

```
public Form1(string s)
{  
    txtTest.Text=s;
}
```

When calling from `Form2`

```
Form1 op = new Form1(Player1);
```

Comment: this is not the answer but this will display the value to `Form1` but the `Form2` will not hide :)

Comment: @spajce- Please explain me why form1 does not hide?

Comment: this is too difficult and we know that.. try to search about the Form behavior in C#. this commonly used in `loginForm` to `MainForm` and try to check my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061746/can-not-focus-onto-a-form

Comment: @spajce- Still I am not clear with your comment.But try to understand it. I run the code. `Form1` gets hide as I can see.